# What does it mean to have 'R^2 larger than chance' (from sklearn docs)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, r-squared, importance

See the following:

[image]

From : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html

The part I'm unsure about is:

> Its validation performance, measured via the
> score, is significantly larger than the chance level

R2 measures the proportion of variance explained by the model, but why should a particular value (in this case 0.356) be considered higher than chance?

Comment: It means that you do a better job of predicting than always guessing the mean of the training values, regardless of input.

Comment: Here, "chance" refers to the model where $Y$ and $X$ are truly unrelated. In the permutation model, there is no systematic relationship between $Y$ and $X$; ie they are unrelated in reality. Nevertheless, by chance alone, every permutation sample will show a random trend, and hence a nonzero Rsquared that is explained purely by chance. Over 1000s of such samples, the distribution of these chance-only Rsquares is found. If your observed value, .356, is larger than most of these (say 95%) values, then it can be said to be "higher than chance," although the phrase is awkward.

Comment: @BigBendRegion thanks, so here they've just asserted that, rather than shown it. They've also stated this prior to doing anything with permutation importance, so I guess my question is - if i was to try and demonstrate that this found R2 value was indeed greater than chance, how would I go about doing so? We've got a single test/train split here and a single model, how do I know (from that output) that the given R2 value is greater than chance? I hope that's clear, cheers

Comment: Start here: 1. You need the distribution of R2 values - one for each permutation. Best if there are 1000s of them. 2. Draw the histogram of these R2 values. 3.  Locate .356 on the horizontal axis.  4. Is it larger than "most" of the histogram? If yes, then in can be characterized as "greater than chance", because of the R2 values in the histogram are explained by chance. (If .356 happened to be well within the range of the chance-only R2 values, then your R2 can be characterized correctly as *explainable by chance alone.*

Answer (score 2):

When you collect data, there is always some chance that, just due to rotten luck, you observe something in the data that is not really there. This is why, for instance, we can observe two groups with unequal empirical means of $\bar x_1$ and $\bar x_2$, yet not immediately conclude that $\mu_1\ne\mu_2$. It could be that, just due to some bad luck, we happen to observe unequal sample means, despite equal population means. In fact, it can be that $\bar x_1<\bar x_2$, yet $\mu_1>\mu_2$, as the simulation below shows.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 5

# Group 1 has the higher population mean mu
#
group1 <- rnorm(N, 0.1, 1)
group2 <- rnorm(N, 0.0, 1)

# Yet group 2 has the higher sample mean x-bar
#
mean(group1) # -0.6522852
mean(group2) # 0.06226405
```

How this relates to regression and an $R^2$ better than chance is that, even if you add a totally unrelated variable to your regression model, it might be that, just due to the luck of what you happen to observe, there is a slight empirical relationship. Therefore, the $R^2$ will increase slightly upon adding the variable, despite the lack of a relationship.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 5
x <- runif(N)
y <- rnorm(N)
L <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(L)$r.squared
```

Despite the fact that the simulation above has `x` and `y` totally unrelated to each other, just due to the luck of the values that happen to be observed/simulated, there is a fairly high $R^2 = 0.784$. If you do this kind of simulation many times, you see that high $R^2$ values can occur fairly often.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 5
R <- 10000
x <- runif(N)
r2 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  y <- rnorm(N)
  r2[i] <- (cor(x, y))^2
}
plot(r2, ecdf(r2)(r2))
abline(v = 0.5)
```

[image: ECDF of R^2 values occurring by chance]

From the graph, we see that about $20\%$ of observed $R^2$ values exceed $0.5$, despite there being absolutely no relationship between `x` and `y`. Therefore, if you run a regression and get $R^2 = 0.5$, despite that looking like a solid score (at least in many cases), it is so easy to get such a value just by chance that that you cannot really consider your performance to be above the chance level.

Fortunately, as the sample size increases, it becomes highly unlikely to observe high $R^2$ values just by chance. For instance, when I bump up the sample size to $50$ (so still not very high), not one $R^2$ value in $10,000$ iterations exceeds $0.28$.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 50
R <- 10000
x <- runif(N)
r2 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  y <- rnorm(N)
  r2[i] <- (cor(x, y))^2
}
max(r2) # 0.2792793
```

Increasing the sample size to $500$ results in a highest observed $R^2$ a bit above $0.03$.

What seems to be happening in that `sklearn` documentation is that feature importance is tested by permuting the values. By doing so, you break any relationship between the feature and the outcome, except for the occasional bad break. When the $R^2$ with the original feature is higher than the vast majority of $R^2$ values the result from permuting the feature, you conclude that there is a true relationship between the feature and your outcome ($y$). I will demonstrate below.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 250
R <- 10000
x <- runif(N)

# Make y depend on x
#
y <- x + rnorm(N)

observed_r2 <- (cor(x, y))^2
r2 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Scramble the values of x to break the dependence
  #
  x <- sample(x, N, replace = F)
  r2[i] <- (cor(x, y))^2
}
plot(r2, ecdf(r2)(r2), xlim = c(0, max(c(r2, observed_r2))))
abline(v = observed_r2)
```

Not one of the $10000$ permutations gave an $R^2$ greater than the observed $R^2$ with the original $x$. That seems like evidence of the $x$ variable being predictive of $y$, which we can see from the simulation is true.

[image: Permutation ECDF with original R^2 as vertical line]

Compare this with a stuation where $x$ has no relationship with $y$.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 250
R <- 10000
x <- runif(N)

# Make y depend on x
#
y <- 0*x + rnorm(N)

observed_r2 <- (cor(x, y))^2
r2 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Scramble the values of x to break the dependence
  #
  x <- sample(x, N, replace = F)
  r2[i] <- (cor(x, y))^2
}
plot(r2, ecdf(r2)(r2), xlim = c(0, max(c(r2, observed_r2))))
abline(v = observed_r2)
```

[image: No relationship between x and y]

Many $R^2$ values with permuted $x$ exceed the observed $R^2$ using the original $x$, suggesting that $x$ is not contributing to predicting $y$ any better than it would be expected to by chance alone.

Where this can be quite useful in a machine learning context is if you have a complicated model. Perhaps you have lots of interaction terms or nonlinear functions of the original features, such as $y = x_1 + x_2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1x_2$, and you just want to know if $x_1$ is a contributor of any kind to $y$. If you permute $x_1$, you can figure that out. I will simulate it below.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 2500
R <- 10000
x1 <- runif(N)
x2 <- runif(N)

# Make y depend on x
#
y <- x2 + x2^2 + rnorm(N)

L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + x1*x2)

observed_r2 <- summary(L)$r.squared
r2 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Scramble the values of x1 to break the dependence
  #
  x1 <- sample(x1, N, replace = F)
  
  L <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + x1*x2)
  
  r2[i] <- summary(L)$r.squared
  
  if (i %% 100 == 0){
    print(i/R*100)
  }
}
plot(r2, ecdf(r2)(r2), xlim = c(min(c(r2, observed_r2)), max(c(r2, observed_r2))))
abline(v = observed_r2)
1 - ecdf(r2)(observed_r2)
```

[image: Permutation test with many features]

About $15\%$ of models with permuted $x_1$ result in $R^2$ exceeding the $R^2$ of the original model. Does that make it sound like $x_1$ plays a role in determining $y?$ I reveal the answer below, but think about it!

> You can see from the code that the x1 variable plays no role in determining y, consistent with the permutation test. After all, when y is determined in the y <- x2 + x2^2 + rnorm(N) line, x1 does not appear at all.