# Why is multiple R squared artificially inflated?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, least-squares, r-squared

Why is multiple $R^2$ artificially inflated? I understand that the value of $R^2$ cannot decrease with additional variables, but why does it increase when an additional variable is added that has no shared variance?

Note: I have looked online and have not found a helpful explanation, only a statement that it is indeed inflated.

Comment: "Artificially inflated" compared to what?  Please note that when you change the variables, *you create a different model.*  Thus, if you are conceiving of the sample $R^2$ as estimating something (such as a population $R^2$), *the meaning of that parameter changes between the two models.*

Comment: For example, $R^2$ with variables $A, B, C, D$ might be .9 whereas $R^2$ with only $A, B, C$ is .8,, even though $D$ shares no unique variance with any other variable.

Comment: This doesn't respond to my comment, though, because your two uses of "$R^2$" refer to two estimates of *two different parameters* in two explicitly different models.

Comment: I am sorry if I am being unclear. I am hoping for an explanation of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Inflation_of_R2

Comment: I cannot find any word related to "artificial" anywhere in that Wikipedia article.  It uses "inflated" only in the sense that the OLS estimate of $R^2$ does not decrease as new columns are added to the design matrix.  ("$R^2$ is at least weakly increasing with increases in the number of regressors in the model.") This is a purely mathematical observation (arising from the fact that when you allow more freedom in a minimization problem, the minimum cannot increase), so it is unclear what you might mean by "artificial."

Comment: Do you mean that the $R^2$ is biased high? That seems to tie back to adjusted $R^2$.

Comment: I mean that the $R^2$ becomes increasingly *larger* when you add variables that share no variance with any other variables in the model.

Comment: @Dave, I removed the [tag:regression] for there was already [tag:multiple-regression] added to it.

Comment: I am inclined to respect the original wishes of the author, unless there is something clearly incorrect about the tag.

Comment: Sure @Dave. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a linear model that is estimated using ordinary least squares (this seems to be the setting you mean), $R^2$ will not decrease, since the model always has the option to set the coefficient on the new variable equal to zero and use the previous coefficients on the other variables, resulting in the same predicted values and same $R^2$ as before.

If, empirically, the added variable is totally unrelated to the outcome, $R^2$ will not increase. However, just because the additional variable has no true relationship with the outcome does not mean that a weak relationship will not be present in the observed data. Just by [(bad) luck](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609309/247274), you are likely to observe some kind of relationship. This is why, even if there is no true relationship, the model $R^2$ is likely to increase: the model has detected a coincidence.